# Colormap in python using an external file

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have an external file with x and y column. I want to color my data based on the y column of the external file in Matplotlib. I am trying like following

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a=np.genfromtxt('rmsd_tonormal3.xvg')

plt.scatter(tica_features[2][:,0],tica_features[2][:,1],a[:,1])
```

That seems working but how to color it based on a[:,1]?

Comment: Could you link your sample file (creating a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) for example), or part of its content?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs on [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), you should use the `c` keyword argument:

> c : color, sequence, or sequence of color, optional, default: ‘b’
>   The marker color. Possible values:
>
> - A single color format string.
> - A sequence of color specifications of length n.
> - A sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using cmap and norm.
> - A 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA.

Your case is the third alternative, that is,  "a sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using `cmap` and `norm`", which are also keyword arguments.

```
plt.scatter(tica_features[2][:,0],tica_features[2][:,1], c=a[:,1], cmap="viridis")
```